# Apache Beam DynamicAvroDestinations DefaultFilenamePolicy with String instead of ResourceId

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

According to the write example on https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html

The following code should work:

```java
public FilenamePolicy getFilenamePolicy(Integer userId) {
    return DefaultFilenamePolicy.fromParams(new Params().withBaseFilename(baseDir + "/user-"
     + userId + "/events"));
}
```

However, when checking the code/documentation for DefaultFilenamePolicy, the function `withBaseFilename` does not accept strings: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/DefaultFilenamePolicy.Params.html

Instead you should provide a ResourceId. Is there any way to specify the basefilename with a string without having to specify sharding etc.?

Comment: This is most likely a bug in the documentation. I don't believe it's possible to specify the base file name as a `String`. `ResourceId`s can be created using `FileSystems.matchNewResource()`.